Question on principal unit groups in local fields
This is a (likely) simple question, but for some reason I can't see it right now.
In Childress's Class Field Theory book, Lemma 2.5, the author claims that $$(1 + \mathfrak{p}_v^t)^n = 1 + \mathfrak{p}_v^{t + r}$$ in the completion $F_v$, where $v$ is a place of a number field $F$, $\mathfrak{p}_v$ is the associated prime ideal, and $r = \operatorname{ord}_v n$. It may also be relevant that $t$ is chosen so that $|n \pi^{t + 1}| \geq | \pi^{2t}|$.
This feels like it should be a simple binomial expansion-type argument, but I don't see how we get the $t + r$ in the exponent.
Many thanks!

That seems incorrect as such. At the very least, you would need to say that $F$ is a local field with maximal ideal $\mathfrak{p}_v$.

Thanks! I've edited for clarity - the equality is claimed to be true in $F_v$, so $\mathfrak{p}_v$ is the maximal ideal in this completion.

See here. The answer is incomplete, but the comment by reuns basically answers the question.
